# Bosonization left and right moving fields in 1D

Tags: conformal-field-theory, bosonization

In’s Senechal’s Bosonization review (https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9908262) for the free boson he defines separate left and right moving parts for the field $\phi$ As $$\phi(x,t)=\phi(x-vt)+\bar{\phi}(x+vt)$$ where

$$\begin{aligned} \phi(z) &=\int_{k>0} \frac{\mathrm{d} k}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 k}}\left[b(k) \mathrm{e}^{-k z}+b^{\dagger}(k) \mathrm{e}^{k z}\right] \\ \bar{\phi}(\bar{z}) &=\int_{k>0} \frac{\mathrm{d} k}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 k}}\left[\bar{b}(k) \mathrm{e}^{-k \bar{z}}+\bar{b}^{\dagger}(k) \mathrm{e}^{k \bar{z}}\right] \end{aligned}$$

A bit further on he says this isn’t quite right because

1. The field being massless, the mode expansion is ill-defined at $k = 0$, because $ω(k = 0) = 0$. The mode at $k = 0$, or zero-mode, has to be treated separately and turns out to be important. The existence of this mode apparently spoils the left-right separation of the field $\phi$.
2. In order for bosonization to be rigorously defined, the field $\phi$ must have an angular character.
   In other words, the target space of the field must be a circle of radius R (to be kept general
   for the moment), so that $\phi$ and $\phi$ + 2$\pi$R are identified. We say that the boson is compactified
   on a circle.
3. A rigorous proof of bosonization procedure (at the spectrum level) is best obtained on a system
   of finite size L with periodic boundary conditions.

But then he concludes that

$$\varphi(x, t)=q+\frac{\pi_{0} v t}{L}+\frac{\tilde{\pi}_{0} x}{L}+\sum_{n>0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi n}}\left[b_{n} \mathrm{e}^{-k z}+b_{n}^{\dagger} \mathrm{e}^{k z}+\bar{b}_{n} \mathrm{e}^{-k \bar{z}}+\bar{b}_{n}^{\dagger} \mathrm{e}^{k \bar{z}}\right]$$

I don’t quite understand how this jump is made. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: On the page after the last equation you quoted, the author says "The operator $q$ is not single-valued, since it is an angular variable..." and goes on to explain that it only makes sense in an exponent. Equation (46) in the paper, the last equation in the OP, is subject to a similar caveat: the field $\varphi(x,t)$ itself is not an observable, even though $\exp(i\varphi(x,t)/R)$ and $\partial_k\varphi(x,t)$ may be observables. Does this address the question?

Comment: I’m interested in how the first three terms come about primarily. I’m guessing that the terms in the summation are just the integral terms taken in a finite system of size L (however, I’m not sure this explains 2 terms turns into 4 in the summation)